# Network Equipment: What is NOT in the box with the equipment?

Tags: cisco, juniper-junos

I am looking at buying some managed switches, a router and a firewall for a laboratory LAN. I am trying to put together some quotes for analyzing my budget and am looking at Cisco and Juniper for now.

Besides the device itself (e.g. router, switch, security appliance), what else should I be looking to include in my shopping list? Do the vendors like Cisco/Juniper provide rack mounts, console cables, power cables, and everything needed to install and setup the devices with the equipment itself? Do I need to be looking for that separately?

Comment: Generally speaking, yes they will provide all you need...but possibly only if you make sure to specifically request (and possibly pay) for it. What you actually need will be entirely based on your situation/environment.

Comment: You need to ask your supplier what they include in the box.

Answer (score 1):

> ... and everything needed to install and setup the devices with the equipment itself?

I can only speak for Cisco, *YES*. You can get everything except a trunk monkey to actually install it. (for larger kit, you'll need to specifically add the necessary rack mounting kit to your order -- 19", 23", cable management, etc. But I'm guessing this lab won't be using a 6509 or 7513)

Comment: No, I was looking at 2960X devices from Cisco.